# In R create dataset of unique values and prioritize elements of duplicates

Tags: r, dataset, unique, priority-queue

I have a dataframe in R that contains several duplicate organizations. I would like to create a new dataframe where each organization is only listed once.

```
OrgName<-c("Org1","Org2","Org3","Org2","Org2","Org3")
ProgramName<-c("P1","P2","P2","P1","P4","P3")
OrgType<-c("Consulting","Education","Government","Government","Consulting","Education")

df<-data.frame(OrgName,ProgramName,OrgType)

df2<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=ncol(df),nrow=length(unique(df$OrgName))))

  OrgName ProgramName    OrgType
1    Org1          P1 Consulting
2    Org2          P2  Education
3    Org3          P2 Government
4    Org2          P1 Government
5    Org2          P4 Consulting
6    Org3          P3  Education
```

I was able to this above for the first column. But in order to populate the subsequent columns I need to indicate which Program Name and Org Type to display since there is more than one value.

I would like to say that in cases where an organization is part of P1, insert use the name of program 1 in the `ProgramName` Field and the associated Org Typ in the `OrgType` field. If an organization is not part of P1, then insert use the name of P2 in the `ProgramName` Field and the associated Org Typ in the `OrgType` field. The seuqence would then prioritize P3 and then P4.

Comment: Maybe `df[as.logical(ave(as.character(df$ProgramName),df$OrgName,FUN=function(x) x==min(x))),]`?

Comment: Thank you @nicola. The Program Names in my actual dataset do not have a number in them and would be based on different rules so i do not think FUN=function(x) x==min(x)) will work. In my actual dataset P1=School, P2=Buildings, P3=Congregations, P4=Services. Could you modify the suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`, convert to `data.table` with `setDT`, grouped by 'OrgName', `order` the 'OrgName', 'ProgramName' and get the first row of the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(OrgName, ProgramName), head(.SD, 1), .(OrgName)]
#   OrgName ProgramName    OrgType
#1:    Org1          P1 Consulting
#2:    Org2          P1 Government
#3:    Org3          P2 Government
```

Comment: Thank you. That appears to work and now I am trying to reproduce this on my actual dataset. I looked in documentation for order to understand what the period and parentheses mean associated with .(OrgName) and what .SD refers to but could not find any information. Could you kindly describe that they do?

Comment: @Danny `.SD` means Subset of Data.table`  the `.(OrgName)` would be the grouping variable

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` option would be to `arrange` your data by `OrgName` and `ProgramName` and then only select the first row per `OrgName`.

```
library(dplyr)
dplyr::arrange(df, OrgName, ProgramName) %>% 
 group_by(OrgName) %>% 
 do(head(., 1)) %>% 
 ungroup()
#  A tibble: 3 x 3
#  OrgName ProgramName OrgType   
#  <fct>   <fct>       <fct>     
#1 Org1    P1          Consulting
#2 Org2    P1          Government
#3 Org3    P2          Government
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `dplyr` to do this -- first `arrange` the df by `OrgName` and `ProgramName`, then pick `distinct` rows on the `OrgName` field but opt to keep all fields:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(OrgName, ProgramName) %>%
  distinct(OrgName, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()

#   OrgName ProgramName    OrgType
# 1    Org1          P1 Consulting
# 2    Org2          P1 Government
# 3    Org3          P2 Government
```